# Conexión a db remota PSQL desde python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, postgresql, tkinter

Intento hacer una conexión con psycopg2 a mi db en LAN corriendo en windows10, pero genera un error que no logro resolver, lei la documentación y me habla del ssl.cert

```
psycopg2.connect(database="access_control", user="postgres", password="password", host="192.168.0.3", port="5432", sslmode='require')
```

Tutos en Linux varios, pero en windows poco, en localhost me funciona sin problema.

Comment: ¿Puedes pegar también el texto del error que te genera?

Comment: Pues pregúntale al DBA que certificado SSL tienes que instalarte.

Comment: Y sino prueba a quitarle sslmode='require' de la cadena de conexión. Eso si los datos ya no irán cifrados